# Delphi: PopupMenu doesn't work in my component

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

English Translation (been a while, so may not be entirely accurate; used google translate for the parts I had trouble with):

I'm working on a Visual Component  in Delphi (it's not a standard Delphi component) which possesses a property called `PopupMenu`. I associated the property `PopupMenu` in the component with the PopupMenu, but when I click the right button [of the mouse], I see nothing.

I also tried to force it to display with this code:

```
x:= Mouse.CursorPos.X; 
y:= Mouse.CursorPos.Y; 
// //showmessage(inttostr(x)) PopupMenu1.Popup(x,y);
```

I have two questions:

How do you know that the right click of the mouse is active? Have any of you encountered this type of problem? Thank you for your answers.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the procedure that I'm using to execute the `PopupMenu1:` procedure

```
TForm6.GeckoBrowser1DOMMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Key: Word); 
var x,y:integer; 
begin 
  if key=VK_RBUTTON then begin 
    x:= Mouse.CursorPos.X; 
    y:= Mouse.CursorPos.Y; 
    //showmessage(inttostr(x)) PopupMenu1.Popup(x,y); 
  end; 
end;
```

Comment: What is the ancestor? Can you give us source code of a simple sample control that displays the thing you consider to be a 'problem'? Why not just check if `MouseButton = mbRight`?

Comment: @user653395 le plupart des gens sur ce site parlent en anglais. Donc, j'ai traduit votre question à anglais.

Comment: Please don't downvote a question just because you can't understand it/it is in a different language.

Comment: here's how I use to run the PopupMenu1:
   procedure TForm6.GeckoBrowser1DOMMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Key: Word);
var x,y:integer;
 
begin
if key=VK_RBUTTON  then
  begin
   x:= Mouse.CursorPos.X;
   y:= Mouse.CursorPos.Y;
   //showmessage(inttostr(x))
   PopupMenu1.Popup(x,y);
  end;
end;
 but PopupMenu1 does not appear in my Visual component.
Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't think localized questions / answers should be accepted here. But if we have the translated text, I think we should keep it deleting the original text.

Comment: @user653395 ajouter de nouvelles informations a la question initiale s'il vous plait

Comment: The problem with the question is that the pertinent information is locked in this non-standard component.

Comment: Popup menu shows on mouse up not mouse down. What's more, you should not have to handle that yourself. Don't you just handle WM_CONTEXTMENU? Finally, why do you need to handle any messages? Surely setting PopupMenu should be enough - let the Delphi framework handle matters.

Comment: I agree with David, if your component is TControl descendant, then it's enough to publish PopupMenu property, because TControl introduces it.

Comment: Or handle OnContextPopup event (it's also introduced in TControl), if you pass True to the Handled parameter of this event, no popup will fires and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: yes normally, delphi manage PopupMenu.mais with my component that is not a standard part of Delphi, I can not display it.
that's why I use the mouse event to display the PopupMenu.

Comment: @user do you know that the context menu can be invoked from the keyboard?

Comment: OnContextPopup, we find where this event?

Comment: But how to use thepopupMenu by the left mouse button ?

Answer (score 0):

This will never work. You cannot mix code in a form with the component code.

I would suggest something like this:

```
interface

type
  TGeckoBrowser = class(....
private
  FPopupmenu: TPopupMenu;
protected
  ...
  procedure MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Key: Word); override;
  ...
published
  property PopupMenu: TPopupMenu read FPopupMenu write FPopupMenu;
end;

implementation

....

procedure TGeckoBrowser.MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Key: Word);
var
  x,y: integer;
begin
  inherited;
  if (key=VK_RBUTTON) and Assigned(PopupMenu) then begin 
    x:= Mouse.CursorPos.X; 
    y:= Mouse.CursorPos.Y;
    PopupMenu.Popup(x,y);
  end; {if}
end;
```

or if you do not want the OnMouseUp to fire when a popup menu appears do:

```
implementation

....

procedure TGeckoBrowser.MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Key: Word);
var
  x,y: integer;
begin
  if (key=VK_RBUTTON) and Assigned(PopupMenu) then begin 
    x:= Mouse.CursorPos.X; 
    y:= Mouse.CursorPos.Y;
    PopupMenu.Popup(x,y);
  end {if}
  else inherited;
end;
```

See the difference? Popupmenu is now a part (well linked part anyway) of your component and not something that just happens to be on the same form.

Comment: Please can you fix it so that it fires on mouse up. And what about keyboard access to context menu?

Comment: If you assign shortcuts to the menu-items Delphi will make use these fire, no extra code required, certainly no OnKeyPress handlers in the component.

Comment: Johan, I tried your function but it does not work.

  What I found is not normal when doing a right click outside of my Geckobrowser (in the form for example), the PopupMenu is displayed. I do not know this problem

Comment: So then you have the popup menu assigned to the form instead of your component.

Comment: @Johan - are you sure with the "Popupmenu is now a part (well linked part anyway) of your component and not something that just happens to be on the same form" ? It's enough to publish PupupMenu property from the ancestor, you'll get access to already existing internal field FPopupMenu, what means you can omit FPopupmenu declaration and in the published section put only "property PopupMenu;"

Comment: but I have owned in my PupupMenu component but the poster is done only in the sheet which bears my component.

Comment: Further answers require a book.

Comment: In the procedure MouseUp (Sender: TObject; Key: Word), I display the value of key but has a value of 63803, so that's why, when making a comparison with "VK_RBUTTON", it displays no the PopupMenu.

is there a way to retrieve the current mouse event (click left or right) without going through the "MouseUp"?

Comment: @user - You can use GetKeyState. But the 'Key' you've got there looks strange, there's something wrong here..

Comment: @Johan Is there an updated version of Gecko? The version mentioned here is `1.9` while the latest one is `29`..

Comment: @Johan see http://sourceforge.net/p/geckobrowser/code/HEAD/tree/ 2010.. too old. Therfore wont even work with newer XE versions.